# Postgres: Don't run a query if current time is in range

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've got a query that needs to be run on an hourly basis to send alerts if the query returns *any* data. To avoid receiving alters at off-hours, I don't want this query to run if the current time is between 12AM and 7AM EST.

Here's how the SQL looks in its current state:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - updated_at))/60) :: INT as minutes_since_update
    FROM table_a
        WHERE column_a IS TRUE AND column_b IS NULL
    LIMIT 1) a
WHERE minutes_since_update > 60
```

How can I alter this query so that it won't run during off-hours.

I've tried this, but I'm not clear on why it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    IF (SELECT CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '11:00:00') THEN
        SELECT 0 as minutes_since_update FROM table_a where true = false;
    ELSE
        SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - updated_at))/60) :: INT as minutes_since_update
        FROM table_a
            WHERE column_a IS TRUE AND column_b IS NULL
        LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
) a
WHERE minutes_since_update > 60
```

Comment: Why not add it to the WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the clause in the WHERE condition.

```
SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - updated_at))/60) :: INT as minutes_since_update
FROM table_a
WHERE column_a IS TRUE AND column_b IS NULL
AND CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:00:00'
LIMIT 1;
```

But, I would probably use something like [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)